# how to know all scheduler and their stored procedure name through query in oracle?

Tags: oracle

There is procedure which is running from a scheduler, I want to know that scheduler name in oracle jobs. I can find it manually but it is time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

try this query

```
select * from all_scheduler_jobs where job_action like '%<name of proc>%'
```

Comment: In this query I need to know procedure name prior, it is not useful for me. I want a query in which scheduler name and their respective procedure names can get.

Comment: @RohitKarambali if you remove the condition and you did the select on all the table wouldnt that work for you